# How to setup one-to-one relation in yii2 and also other functionalities mentioned below

Tags: yii, yii2

One User has One Profile(obviously). How do I design the logic behind this?

- I have two tables namely "tbl_users" and "tbl_profile".
- When I open the profile page, I should be able to see the "Create
  Profile" button only if the profile does not exist.
- Once the profile has been created by the user, "Create Profile"
  button should not appear next time.
- Please describe me in detail how the columns of both tables are linked and what changes I have to include in both the models and other changes too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you could write something like this:

```
$user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
$profile = $user->profile;
return $this->render('view', ['user' => $user, 'profile' => $profile]);
```

Then in your view

```
if(null !== $profile) {
    /*show your button here. It's going to work once because...*/
} else {
    /*...here you could show form to create your profile*/
}
```

In your User model use code like this

```
public function getProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::className(), ['id' => 'profile_id']);
}
```

This is just an example to give you idea.